# Ruby on rails updating model via rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, rails-console

I have run rails g model Task description:text. Then I have run rails console and put in a few tasks. I would now like to add more attributes to the create_tasks.rb file. Such as  .string :title.

What I tried:

1. opened the file(create_tasks.rb), put the new line in. Then ran `rake
   db:migrate` then went back into the console and opened the first task
   and it doesn't show the title attribute.
2. also tried creating a new task using the title attribute. `Error:
   unknown title attribute for Task`.

So, how do I update the model?

Comment: General comment—it's _usually_ better to create a new migration for each db change, instead of changing existing migrations. That way, every dev on a project can simply run the new migrations without needing to rollback, mess around, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `rails db:rollback` to roll the database back before the latest migration, add the new variables to the migration file, then run `rails db:migrate` to have the new parts of the migration file included.

If you need to roll back more revisions (if you have created more migrations since you created this model), you can either include the number of roll backs like

```
rails db:rollback STEP=<enter number of steps>
#e.g. rails db:rollback STEP=2
```

or, you could also `rails db:reset` which would remove all databases, recreate them, then remigrate them.  Or you could `rails db:drop` to drop the database, then `rails db:create` and `rails db:migrate` to migrate the new database.

Do not edit the schema file.  The schema file is automatically updated when you run migrations etc to match the content of your migration files.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Rails!

Here you can find some tutorials about how to deal with migrations:

- http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html
- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-migrations.htm

Basically, every time you want to modify a migration, you must:

1. run `rake db:rollback`
2. modify the migration
3. run `rake db:migrate`

I hope this helps. Good coding!!